# Symfony2 How to pass in $year, $month variables to Twig without hardcoding first?

Tags: php, variables, symfony, twig

I'm trying to pass in a two variables to Twig without hardcoding it first in the controller. I am looking for a simple solution and nothing too excessive.

Right now per the controller code below, it's showing the counts for July in every month that I use, which is what I don't want.

The end result of what I'm trying to do is show the monthly post counts in a sidebar.

**e.g., June (3), July (5) etc.**

In the controller I am using the year and month hardcoded in and passing it to Twig.

**How can I do this so, I don't have to hard code it in the controller / so that it takes variables from Twig (for example 'year': '2014', 'month': 'current month' ?**

I tried this which works but it is a terrible solution:

```
$month1 = $em->getRepository('AcmeDemoBundle:Post')
    ->getPostCountsByMonth('2014', 'June');

$month2 = $em->getRepository('AcmeDemoBundle:Post')
    ->getPostCountsByMonth('2014', 'July');

return $this->render('AcmeDemoBundle:Page:index.html.twig', array(
    'month1' => $month1,
    'month2' => $month2
));
```

---

**Controller:**

```
$month = $em->getRepository('AcmeDemoBundle:Post')
        ->getPostCountsByMonth('2014', 'July'); <--- what I don't want to do

return $this->render('AcmeDemoBundle:Page:index.html.twig', array(
        'month' => $month,
));
```

**Twig:**
(Have tried the following but doesn't work: `{{ month, { 'year': '2014', 'month': 'July' } }}`)

```
July 2014 ({{ month }})
```

**Repository:**

```
public function getPostCountsByMonth($year, $month)
{
    $date = new \DateTime("{$year}-{$month}-01");
    $toDate = clone $date;
    $toDate->modify("next month midnight -1 second");

    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('post')
        ->where('post.created BETWEEN :start AND :end')
        ->addOrderBy('post.created', 'DESC')
        ->setParameter('start', $date)
        ->setParameter('end', $toDate);

    $query->select('COUNT(post.created)');

    $month = $query
        ->getQuery()
        ->getSingleScalarResult();

    return $month;
}
```

Comment: I don't get it. You want to inject year and month into the controller?

Comment: I want to set it up so I don't have to set the year/month in the controller and use a variable in Twig for that.

Comment: I would advise either passing a year into the template or creating a twig extension that gets the month for you. Then your twig would just be `{{ getCount('2014','july') }}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to go about is to write a twig extension, this is a basic example and could probably be optimized depending on what you want to do.

```
namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Twig;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager

class PostExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    private $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $em){
        $this->em  = $em;
    }
    public function getFilters()
    {
        return array(

        );
    }

    public function getFunctions(){
        return array(
            'getPostCount' => new \Twig_Function_Method($this,'getPostCount')
        );
    }

    public function getPostCount($year,$month)
    {
        return $this->em->getRepository('AcmeDemoBundle:Post')
            ->getPostCountsByMonth($year, '$month');
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'post_extension';
    }
}
```

Basicly you are creating your own twig filter. If you haven't done this before consult the docs http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html

Or as I said in the comment you could write a repo function that gets all counts by month and just pass that to your template.

Either way, it's all about injecting what you want.

**Edit** changed from twig filter to twig function.

Also you want to pass the entity manager into the service as an argument like so:

```
your_service_name:
            class: Acme\DemoBundle\Twig\PostExtension
            tags:
                - { name: twig.extension }
            arguments:
                em: "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"
```

Comment: Ok I've set this up and am getting `The function "getPostCount" does not exist in AcmeDemoBundle:Page:index.html.twig at line 17` am using the following in Twig: `{{ getPostCount('2014', 'July') }}`. Where do I pass this is in from?

Comment: Used the following setup in services.yml: `services:
    acme.twig.acme_extension:
        class: Acme\DemoBundle\Twig\PostExtension
        tags:
            - { name: twig.extension }`

Comment: I've edited my post, I originally wrote it as a twig filter, it probably needs to be a twig function. Try the new code and make sure you pass the entity manager into the service.

Comment: Getting the following error: `ErrorException: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Acme\DemoBundle\Twig\PostExtension::__construct() must be an instance of Acme\DemoBundle\Twig\EntityManager, instance of Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager given, called in /var/www/Symfony/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 737 and defined in /var/www/Symfony/src/Acme/DemoBundle/Twig/PostExtension.php line 12` and line 12: `public function __construct(EntityManager $em)`

Comment: You should learn about oop and php if you want to use symfony =/. You did not tell php that you wanted to use that class and namespace. It's assuming Entity Manager is part of your script and namespace.

You must add `use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager`

Comment: Sigh, yes I missed that use statement. Just new to the whole Twig Extension thing. That fixed that error, now I get this `FatalErrorException:Error:Cannot access property in /../PostExtension.php line 32` Line 32: `public function getPostCount($year, $month)`

Comment: problem was with `return $this->$em->getRepository('AcmeDemoBundle:Post')` typo in $em. `return $this->em->getRepository('AcmeDemoBundle:Post')`

Comment: Excellent! I'm glad you got that resolved. Symfony is a pretty cool framework and I'm just getting into it my self

Comment: Question, where did you find the setup for creating a twig function? I saw how to setup a twig filter but not the setup you showed me for the twig function.

Comment: Gosh I always try and find a reference for that and I can barely find anything =/.  I learned to use them mostly through guess work. If you find anything related to that I'd love to know.